# Disable Chrome autofill popup

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, autofill

I'm just curious if there is a full proof way to disable this Chrome suggestion popup. I've tried Googling for the answer but they all seem to point to using `autocomplete="off"` but as you can see, it already has this and it's not helping..

As you can also see here, it's quite disruptive to our form field and hides the options behind, is there a way we can prevent this from happening for customers using Chrome?

[Chrome popup disrupting our form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mky2o.png)

I would like to imagine there is a nice easy HTML solution here so hoping someone can point me in the right direction..

Comment: It looks like the chrome password manager not autofill. Are you sure you're not somehow making Chrome think you're asking for a login?

Comment: Hmmn ok thanks for the tip I will try find time to look into it further. I didn't write the code and it's using some fancy select which is likely complicating things. The answer might be just replacing it with a bare bone input select. I can't see anything obvious in the code. All good thanks :)